# How can I get 2 containers to link when I get an EOF error

Tags: docker

I have docker-io set up on my machine and my user belongs to the docker group, so I have no trouble running docker images.  I have an image based on node:0.10.38 and can run it like so:

```
docker run -d --name=original_node --expose=5858,8081 \
  -v /opt/users/pwebster:/opt/users/pwebster \
  pwebster/openacademy:v01 node --debug server.js \
  -c /opt/users/pwebster/orion/nodejs/search-orion.conf
```

This works fine.  When I go to link my second container to the first, it fails with a somewhat cryptic error:

```
docker run  --link=original_node:pw --name=link_node \
  -v /opt/users/pwebster:/opt/users/pwebster -ti \
  pwebster/openacademy:v01 /bin/bash -l
```

This command then returns an error:

```
FATA[0001] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/containers/9af64a9c282b3fbec613eec2f79f05b12919a5c558f722a0ccb292b2e96ec475/start: EOF. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

There hasn't been anything special about these configurations, and a search returns lots of `Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?` which seems to be the default error message, but none that mention the Post failure has "/start" at the end.

It's only including the `--link` that causes the `docker run` to fail.  Any hints are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: docker -d -D log

When I run the image a second time with `/bin/bash` and `--link`, I get the following in `/var/log/docker`

```
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="debug" msg="Calling POST /containers/{name:.*}/start" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="info" msg="POST /v1.16/containers/6f14a062cd1589d2c40238ec04042f54c7092702bad1a8ec977099aa3addfa67/start" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="info" msg="-job allocate_interface(6f14a062cd1589d2c40238ec04042f54c7092702bad1a8ec977099aa3addfa67) = OK (0)" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="info" msg="+job link(-I)" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="info" msg="-job link(-I)" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="info" msg="-job start(6f14a062cd1589d2c40238ec04042f54c7092702bad1a8ec977099aa3addfa67)" 
2015/04/22 08:49:19 http: panic serving @: strconv.ParseUint: parsing "5858,8081": invalid syntax
goroutine 73 [running]:
net/http.func·011()
    /usr/lib/golang/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1100 +0xb7
runtime.panic(0xa38a20, 0xc2080e4600)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 +0x18d
github.com/docker/docker/nat.Port.Int(0xc20863f300, 0xd, 0xc20863f30a)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-1.4.1/_build/src/github.com/docker/docker/nat/nat.go:57 +0x98
github.com/docker/docker/daemon/networkdriver/bridge.LinkContainers(0xc2084f2f80, 0x7f25313d78a8)
[...snip...]
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="debug" msg="Closing buffered stdin pipe" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="debug" msg="attach: stdin: end" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="debug" msg="attach: job 1 completed successfully" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="debug" msg="attach: waiting for job 2/3" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="debug" msg="attach: stdout: end" 
time="2015-04-22T08:49:19-04:00" level="debug" msg="attach: stderr: end"
```

I guess the implication is that it doesn't like my `--expose=5858,8081`

Comment: run the daemon with debug with `docker -d -D` (extract from https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/) and post the messages

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, it really helped with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `--expose=5858,8081` on my original container to `--expose=5858 --expose=8081` and the problem went away.

Looks like I was misusing the expose flag.